# Single app registration in Azure for mobile app calling own backend

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, microsoft-identity-platform

I want to authenticate users with Azure Active Directory (AD) in a mobile app that calls its own REST API and possibly, make it simple.

Looks like the documented way ([here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-1-MyOrg) or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-mobile-app-registration#api-permissions)) to do so is to

1. register the API app with AD, expose some scope(s) as delegated permissions
2. register the mobile app, add these scopes as API permissions to this app
3. do authorization decisions in the API app based on these scopes

**Question:**
Now, since I feel the front-end and back-end parts of my app should belong into the same "black box" plus there are no fine-granular user roles within the app that would justify usage of multiple scopes or require the user to consent to using them, I'm wondering whether there is a recommended (and secure) way to go with just one app registration instead of two?

**What I tried:**
When using Okta in a similar scenario, I only had one app (clientId) and the back-end configuration pretty much validated the JWT token issuer, domain and a default audience string (in my understanding). I tried inspecting tokens from AD acquired via the authorization code flow for usual scopes (openid profile) to see what their audience was and if this could be reproduced - this is what I've got:

- the well known GUID of Microsoft Graph (for the access token) - this one doesn't feel "correct" to validate, as pretty much any AD user could present an access token for MS Graph and only assigned users should be able to use my app
- client ID of the app (for the ID token) - but the docs [says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens) these should not be used for authorization, so not sure if it's a great idea to pass them as Bearer tokens to the API

Answer (score 0):

The standard thing in OAuth technologies is to only register a client for your mobile app. Azure has some vendor specific behaviour when it comes to APIs, related to the [resource indicators spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8707.html). When there is no API registration, your mobile app will receive JWT access tokens with a `nonce` field in the JWT header. These are intended to be sent to Graph, and will fail validation if you ever try to validate them in your own APIs.

If like me you want to stay close to standards, one option is to add a single  logical app registration, to represent your set of APIs. You might design an audience of `api.mycompany.com`, though Azure will give you a technical value like `cb398b43-96e8-48e6-8e8e-b168d5816c0e`. You can then expose scopes, and use them in client apps. This is fairly easy to manage. Some info in my [blog post](https://authguidance.com/azure-ad-troubleshooting/) from a couple of years back might help clarify this.

Comment: Your blog post series also has two app registrations (BasicSPA and BasicAPI) and you suggest consolidating multiple API services with just one app registration, which goes beyond the scope of what I've asked. Is then your answer to my question a "no"?

Comment: It's no if you want to use custom access tokens in your own APIs - as in my case - in that case you'll need at least one registration for APIs.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, since I feel the front-end and back-end parts of my app should belong into the same "black box" plus there are no fine-granular user roles within the app that would justify usage of multiple scopes or require the user to consent to using them, I'm wondering whether there is a recommended (and secure) way to go with just one app registration instead of two?

You can create just one app registration; in fact the newer app registration model was designed to do that.
In the case where an API is used only by the app itself, I would register a single scope, something like MobileApp.Access.
Your API should verify the presence of this scope to prevent unauthorized applications from calling it.

In addition to verifying the scope, you will need to verify user permissions.
And filter the data based on their identity, depending on your use case.

Your question seems to suggest that you might be mixing scopes and user roles.
Scopes are permissions given to an application.
Also called delegated permissions; they allow an app to do some actions on behalf of the signed in user.

Comment: Does that mean my app registration will contain both redirect URIs and expose an API? And the FE configuration is aware of the client secret and requests the exposed API scope when doing authorization code flow and uses the access token it gets as a result to call the API? Is there any documented sample you can recommend that sums it up?

Comment: Your API won't need a redirect URI. Your front-end should not have a client secret as it is a public client. It needs to use a flow that does not use a secret.

Comment: ...which is the case with Authorization Code Flow with PKCE, I suppose. However, when using the same app registration for API and iOS/Android clients I still have to add those "fake" redirect URIs as described here, right? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-mobile-app-registration#platform-configuration-and-redirect-uris

Comment: You will need the redirect URIs needed by your mobile app, yes.